# Safari refresh prevents jQuery execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, drupal-7, page-refresh

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site, the mobile version of the site which uses Bootsrap as theme.

There is a custom block (created w/ drupal) using jQuery to move some elements on a page, changing some classes and IDs. This block works just fine.

My problem is in a custom module which renders a block. I have some jQuery code in the module's template that is not running on refresh in Safari, but it runs if I go on the address bar and hit "Go" on the keyboard.

edit: IE and Chrome seem to also have a problem, but the jQuery code runs sometimes, doesn't matter if is a refresh, clear cache or whatever.
Nothing special in browser's console.

My jQuery code is supposed to move some elements in the page, on `jQuery(document).ready`, but is not even working for a simple `alert`.

p.s.: the jQuery in my custom module's template doesn't have anything to do with the code or the HTML elements affected by the custom block, but I thought maybe it would be good to mention it.

I hope you can understand the issue :)

Thanks.

Comment: nope! i really didn't understand it. Want to give it another shot?

Comment: @TheWarlock, thanks for the interest.
... well, basically I have some jQuery code that runs only sometimes.
For example, in Safari it works only when I type the address and press "enter" or "go", but not if I do a refresh.
In other browsers it works randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `jQuery(document).ready` to execute my code. I changed to `jQuery(window).load` and now it works fine. The code executes on first page load and on every refresh.

Answer (score 0):

After like two weeks and almost killing myself, this is only thing that worked for ios safari.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      DoLoad();     
    }, 180);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and tried probably a dozen or more ways to address an issue with Safari. It looks like Safari triggers $(window).on('load',...) jQuery call before DOM completely builds. Or perhaps there is some kind of timing/racing condition. In my case, it was causing an issue, but only after page reloads, only with Safari, and only with a certain cloud provider. Chrome was fine, on prem hosting was fine. The only way which worked somewhat reliably was to introduce an artificial delay via setTimeout() function.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  setTimeout(() => {

    $.getScript('{{url}}').done(function(){
      $("#element").js_function({
        arguments
    });
   
    });

  }, 360);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as a code sample, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).